# Screen flickering using glutBitmapCharacter()?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to make a game using OpenGL. My game is working well but i want to display the score. I managed to display it using glutBitmapCharacter but the screen started [flickering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTOmCVMIcSY).

```
void drawBitmapText(char *string) 
{  
char *c;
glWindowPos3f(10,1000,0);

for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++) 
{
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, *c);

}
//glutPostRedisplay();

}

void AffichageScore(int scoreAafficher){ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    std::string scoreSTR = std::to_string(scoreAafficher);
    scoreSTR = "Score : "+scoreSTR;
    int len = scoreSTR.length();
    char scoreArray[len+1];
    std::strcpy(scoreArray, scoreSTR.c_str()); 

    drawBitmapText(scoreArray);
    //glutSwapBuffers();

    //glutPostRedisplay();

}


static void end(){

}



static void timer_callback(int)
{
move_trees();
move_floor();
score += 1;
printf("Score : %d \n",score);  




//demande de rappel de cette fonction dans 25ms
glutTimerFunc(25, timer_callback, 0);

//vérifie la présence de collisions toutes les 25ms
bool verif_col=collisions();
if (verif_col==true){
    int scoreFinal = score;
    fin = true;        
    //AffichageScore(scoreFinal);

    }


glutPostRedisplay();


//reactualisation de l'affichage
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: I dont think you should call glClear every time you want to redraw the score. It should be done once per render pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem !

Answer (score 0):

"I dont think you should call glClear every time you want to redraw the score. It should be done once per render pass" from Three.

This solved the problem.